# Skip first few lines of log using grok filter plugin

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

Is it possible to remove the whole first line starting with date-time in the following log? I'm only interested in the second line.

```
Dec 09, 2019 12:55:22 PM hudson.slaves.CommandLauncher launch
INFO: agent launched for ci-vd6
```

How can I do the above using the grok filter plugin ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention. These two lines are combined as one message and then, I need to filter or drop off the 1st line. How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can skip lines like that:

```
if [message] =~ /2019/ {
  drop { }
}
```

Now you need to change `regex` to drop lines when you need it only.

**EDIT:** For example `baudsp` suggests the regex could look like that:

```
\b(?:[Jj]an(?:uary|uar)?|[Ff]eb(?:ruary|ruar)?|[Mm](?:a|ä)?r(?:ch|z)?|[Aa]pr(?:il)?|[Mm]a(?:y|i)?|[Jj]un(?:e|i)?|[Jj]ul(?:y)?|[Aa]ug(?:ust)?|[Ss]ep(?:tember)?|[Oo](?:c|k)?t(?:ober)?|[Nn]ov(?:ember)?|[Dd]e(?:c|z)(?:ember)?)\b \d{2}, \d{4}
```

I mean scenario when you receive message line by line, so you receive:

> Dec 09, 2019 12:55:22 PM hudson.slaves.CommandLauncher launch

You drop it.

You receive line:

> INFO: agent launched for ci-vd6

you keep it.

**Edit:** to split lines:

Split the message regarding for example newline if possible.
Enable special signs in `logstash.yml`:
`config.support_escapes: true`
and add filter

```
filter {
  split {
  field => "message"
  terminator => "\n" 
 }
}
```

And now process them one by one.

Comment: I don't think having a configuration break each time the year change is a good idea. The comparison should be done on a more general regex, like this one: `\b(?:[Jj]an(?:uary|uar)?|[Ff]eb(?:ruary|ruar)?|[Mm](?:a|ä)?r(?:ch|z)?|[Aa]pr(?:il)?|[Mm]a(?:y|i)?|[Jj]un(?:e|i)?|[Jj]ul(?:y)?|[Aa]ug(?:ust)?|[Ss]ep(?:tember)?|[Oo](?:c|k)?t(?:ober)?|[Nn]ov(?:ember)?|[Dd]e(?:c|z)(?:ember)?)\b \d{2}, \d{4}` (the first part check all the different months, taken from the logstash patterns)

Comment: @baudsp sure, it was just an example. As i wrote "Now you need to change regex to drop lines when you need it only." I edited the answer providing also your regex example.

Comment: @KamilWitkowski Sorry, I forgot to mention. These two lines are combined as one message and then, I need to filter or drop off the 1st line. How to achieve this ?

Comment: @sourav19 Split the message regarding for example `newline` if possible. I edited the answer.